# UITextField Number formatter when setting or editing text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UITextField that I have formatting code attached on **textFieldDidEndEditing:**.  This works fine, but when I first load the text field with a text value (**someTextField.text = @"..."**) the formatting doesn't happen.  Of course, I can add another formatter there, but it seems kind of repetitive.

Is there a way to make *all* changes to a UITextField, programmatic or user originated, have formatting applied automatically?

Comment: Did you try `UITextFieldDidChangeNotification`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the same method from both places...

```
- (void)setTextFieldWithText:(NSString *)text {
    //do formatting here...
    self.textField.text = formattedText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add UITextFieldDidChangeNotification or just add a observer(using the addObserver method) to observe changes to the textfield. Choose which suits your approach. Both of them does cut the repetitive code. [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html) - concept related to your question.

you might get some idea if you take a look at the following links
UITextFieldDidChangeNotification - [How do i notify changes in UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715591/how-do-i-notify-changes-in-uitextfield)

addObserver method - [detecting the change of content of UITextField when the change is not made by the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952177/detecting-the-change-of-content-of-uitextfield-when-the-change-is-not-made-by-th)

```
  Note: Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO, you can still implement it in the custom objects of your application, including custom views.
```

Comment: Regarding your highlighting of the note "Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO...": the text property does appear to provide the KVO I need to do this without subclassing.  How should I interpret this note?  Will it break down on me some day?

Comment: That note was meant for Subclassing UItextView and still more but since you do not want to subclass you can always use UITextFieldDidChangeNotification. Nothing is gonna break down if you implement it exactly it should be. Most of developers use observers to observer changes in their modules so its not new to be worried about.